# UTF-8 Tab Separated File not opening in Excel properly

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

I am generating tab separated .xls file from SAP MII using XSLT which has few french characters as headers/columns.

When I open this file in excel, all special characters are messed up and does not appear correctly.

Such as `Description Ã©vÃ¨nement`

When I store this file as .txt and open it in notepad, everything is displayed correctly.

It seems that Excel is not opening this file in UTF-8 formay but opens by default in ASCII format.

How do I avoid that?

Soham

Comment: Huh, a tab-separated XLS file? Really? Don't you actually mean a CSV file?

Comment: I am storing it as an.xls file . Does it make any difffrence?

Comment: XLS is a binary format like DOC, PDF, EXE, PNG, etc (unreadable in a text editor like Notepad), not a text format like TXT, RTF, HTML, SVG, etc (readable in a text editor like Notepad). A tab separated file sounds much like a `.csv` file. Renaming that to `.xls` would obviously only end up in disaster because it's not a real XLS file at all. Either just use the `.csv` extension (Excel understands it) or create a **real** XLS file. As an example, create a sample XLS file using Excel and try to open it in Notepad. You'll see that it's absolutely not in a text based format.

Comment: OK. I created that file as .csv but when I open it in excel, special charcaters of frenchare still messed up coz excel is opening it in ASCII while my .csv file is in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open excel then import the CSV off the data tab. UTF-8 will be recognized during the import. That said, I do need the ability to do this by simply double clicking on the CSVs.